# Angular Bootstrap Accordion issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create accordion to loop my data.it is partially working, but I need to dynamically add new part into accordion. at beginning I need to open the first one, but after user save it and click add,I need to open the second one, and close others. My code is:

```
<accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
        <accordion-group 
             heading="{{destination.length}}" 
             is-open="status.isFirstOpen" 
             is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled" 
             ng-repeat="destination in mileage.destionations">
                <select ng-model='destination.Type' 
                    id='type' 
                    ng-options='Type for Type in mileageTypes' 
                    ng-init='mileageTypes[0]' 
                    ng-change='updateReimbur(destination)'>
                </select>
                <select ng-model='destination.Reimbursable' 
                    id='reimbursable' 
                    disabled="true" 
                    ng-options='reimbursable for reimbursable in mileageReimbursment' 
                    ng-init='mileageReimbursment[0]'>
                </select>
        </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
```

JS:

```
$scope.mileage.destionations = [{
    Type: '',
    Reimbursable: "Yes",
    Distance: true,
    Odometer: false,
    Total: 0,
    From: '',
    To: ''
}];
$scope.addNewDestionation = function () {
    $scope.NewDestionation = {
        type: '',
        reimbursable: "Yes",
        Distance: true,
        Odometer: false,
        total: 0,
        From: '',
        To: ''
    }
    $scope.mileage.destionations.push($scope.NewDestionation);
}
$scope.status = {
    isFirstOpen: true,
    isFirstDisabled: false
};
```

How can I always leave the last one(New one) open and close the others?

Comment: Not clear what the question is about. What prevents from applying required logic to `$scope.status` inside `$scope.addNewDestionation`?

Comment: You wrote `close-others="oneAtATime"` as in official ui-bootstrap example, but I don't see the declaration of the variable `oneAtATime` in your javascript. Try simply `close-others="true"`

Comment: What's the expected effect of `ng-init` in the `select` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you will get that working, by following these hints :

1. Replace `close-others="oneAtATime"` with `close-others="true"`.
2. On **all the repeated elements**, you are writing : `is-open="status.isFirstOpen"`, which is equivalent to `is-open="true"`. This is your main mistake, as you're saying all groups should be opened.
   Try to maintain a reference to the opened group. You could maintain an array of statuses but something like that will also do the trick, and avoid you to maintain all statuses :

   ```
        is-open="status[$index].isOpen" 
        is-disabled="status[$index].isDisabled"
   ```

`$index` is an angular variable that references the index of the repeated element in the array. I leave you the js logic for the maintenance of the `status` object.

3. For the sake of style, correct the typo in `destionations` (`destinations`), initialize your default new destination in a variable outside the function `addNewDestionation`, and push that variable. Like that :

   ```
   var newDestination = {
       type: '',
       reimbursable: 'Yes',
       Distance: true,
       Odometer: false,
       total: 0,
       From: '',
       To: ''
   };

   $scope.addNewDestionation = function () {
       $scope.mileage.destionations.push(newDestination);
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for your answer, now I understand my mistake, but the problem, is I need to dynamically add new section into this accordion group, what I want is always keep the last one open and leave others closed, for example, if I click add,there will be new section added(will be opened and close others). how can I let the accrodion know I need to always open the last $index.?

Comment: Sure. When you push a new section in the array, réinitialize the status object and activate the flag *isOpened* for the element at the last position. Something like : `status = {}; status[destArray.length - 1] = {isOpened: true}`, where *destArray* is your destination array.

Comment: Like that, for all but the last section, `status[$index].isOpened` will be undefined, and won't be opened as undefined is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

close-others attribute takes a boolean value. You should either define

```
$scope.oneAtATime = true
```

or

```
<accordion close-others = "true">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've undestood it correctly you could do it like this.

Add a property `openState` to your destination object and change it like you need it. So keeping the second active could be done be setting every state to `false` except the second one. 
It's similar to `2.` form Michael's answer and I also think creating a `status` variable to keep track of the open states is probably better here.

Please have a look at the demo below (it's a reduced version of your code to keep things easier to read) or here at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/xov11eaa/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('mainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope) {
    var itemCount = 0; // just to have an increasing title
    $scope.oneAtATime = true;
    $scope.mileage = {};
    $scope.mileage.destionations = [{
        Type: '',
        Reimbursable: "Yes",
        Distance: true,
        Odometer: false,
        total: itemCount,
        From: '',
        To: '',
        openState: true
    }];
    $scope.addNewDestination = function () {
        var index = $scope.mileage.destionations.length,
            openState = (index == 1);
        
        angular.forEach($scope.mileage.destionations, function(destination, index) {
            // turn all off except second
            destination.openState = (index == 1);
        });
        
        itemCount++;
        
        var newDestination = {
            type: '',
            reimbursable: "Yes",
            Distance: true,
            Odometer: false,
            total: itemCount,
            From: '',
            To: '',
            openState: openState
        };
        
        
        $scope.mileage.destionations.push(newDestination);
    }
    $scope.status = {
        isFirstOpen: true,
        isFirstDisabled: false
    };
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.2/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group is-open="destination.openState" heading="{{destination.total}}" ng-repeat="destination in mileage.destionations">
      {{destination|json}}
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
    <button ng-click="addNewDestination()">add</button>
</div>
```